# Select the largest number of countries from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database likes this:
- ID --- COUNTRY

This database is filled with data, and there are lots of double entries, but they should be there. What I am trying to do, is select the country with most entries in the database, but still don't know how to put a query together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT `COUNTRY`, count(`COUNTRY`) FROM `table` GROUP BY `COUNTRY`;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select `country`, count(`country`) as 'count' from `table` group by `country` order by `count` DESC LIMIT, 0,1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, country, COUNT(*) as total FROM table GROUP BY country ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1
```